# Creating a ternary condition in c#

Tags: c#

I have the below datatable code in c# , which I want to make it as a ternary operator condition.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[2].ToString()))
                            {
                                if (row[2].ToString().Length >= 3)
                                {
                                    row[2] = row[2].ToString().Substring(0, 3).ToUpper();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    row[2] = row[2].ToString().ToUpper();
                                }
                            }
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you want to use the ternary operator, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to achieve this ?

just copy your predicate, true expression, and false expression to the ternary form:

```
row[2] = {predicate} ? {true expression} : {false expression}
```

which gives:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[2].ToString()))
{
    row[2] = row[2].ToString().Length >= 3 
           ? row[2].ToString().Substring(0, 3).ToUpper();
           : row[2].ToString().ToUpper();
}
```

you could simplify it a bit by factoring out the common expression:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[2].ToString()))
{
    row2 = row[2].ToString().ToUpper();
    row[2] = row2.Length >= 3 
           ? row2.Substring(0, 3);
           : row2;
}
```

you *could* use a ternary operator for the last `if` and just set `row[2]` to itself if the condition doesn't match, but it's not a functional improvement and is harder to read IMHO.

Comment: what is `Left()`?. I dont think it is a part of string API

Comment: @Lesiak gahh I've been switching around languages too much lately :) removed.

Answer (score 2):

[Ternary operator C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

> The conditional operator ?:, also known as the ternary conditional
>   operator, evaluates a Boolean expression and returns the result of one
>   of the two expressions, depending on whether the Boolean expression
>   evaluates to true or false.
>
> The syntax for the conditional operator is as follows:
>
> C#
>
> condition ? consequent : alternative

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[2].ToString()))
{
    row[2] = row[2].ToString().Length >= 3
        ? row[2].ToString().Substring(0, 3).ToUpper()
        : row[2].ToString().ToUpper();
}
```